# lucky to have met / met / meet someone

Tags: sentence-choice

In a scenario, if you met someone a few days ago for the very first time and then you met again today and after spending time together, you feel lucky to know him/her because you think you will get on well  with him/her in the future and help each other.
How would you tell him/her it today. Note that, it is not important to meet at a specific time. This sentence could be said in tenth meeting or even one year later after the first met.

> I am/feel so lucky to have met you.
>
> I am/feel so luck to met you.
>
> I am feel so lucky to meet you.

Answer (score 2):

When meeting someone for the first time, we commonly say:

"(I'm) pleased to meet you" or "It's nice to meet you" (when being introduced)

and
"I'm pleased to have met you" or "It was nice to meet you" or "It was nice meeting you" (on departing)

In the situation you describe:

> you feel lucky to know him/her because you think you will get well with him/her in the future and help each other.

I would say "I'm really pleased we met" or "I'm so glad we met" and might also add "I look forward to seeing you again/getting to know you better/working with you"

You would only say: "I am so lucky to have met you", if someone had just saved your life or given you a million dollars, or something similar - it's a statement of fact.

"I feel so lucky to have met you" would be acceptable to express a very strong feeling, but again implies that the other person is going to do something amazing for you.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please  elaborate why we cannot say "be lucky to met you"

Comment: It's the wrong verb tense. You would have to say "I feel so lucky to have met you", or "I feel so lucky that I met you" (some people leave the "that" out, but it sounds wrong to me without it).

Comment: then I can say " I was lucky to met him, (otherwise I would have...)" because they are all past tense.

Comment: No, you would say "I was lucky to meet him" - to meet is the infinitive. Just like you would say "I was lucky to score a goal".
You would use the past tense with "to have": "I was lucky to have met him" or "I was lucky to have scored a goal".

Answer (score 1):

> I am so lucky to have met you

You use this to refer to the first meeting, which I think is the likeliest case.

> I am so lucky to met you

This is ungrammatical because "to" requires a bare-infinitival complement.

> I am so lucky to meet you

This is grammatical. You use it to refer to the habitual meeting. But I believe this is rare, because usually only the first meeting was accidental. The second or third meeting is usually scheduled and has nothing to do with luck.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further "bare- infinitival complement" or do you have a link explaining it in a simple way ( I mean not in academic way) please?

Comment: That is another question but can I say " I was lucky to met him" . Is this imply he is death now?